# Is that even feasable?: user click on a button on my website -> get data from another website -> display this data on my website

Tags: javascript, web

I tried to be the most explicit possible and I know I can do it in python but i'm trying to do it in javascript.

the data is in sms/tweet style and length so not very huge and I know where it's located on the other website

Comment: Yes, it is possible - websites pull data from other websites (that have API's) all the time

Comment: yes, it's common and simple scenario

Comment: thanks guys, but it's plain text there's no api to pull data from, so where can i start, queries?

Comment: If the data you're talking about is in the HTML of the other website you can look into web scraping using something like cheerio.js.

Answer (score 0):

If the website you want to scrape is configured to allow cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), you can have the client scrape it.

Otherwise, your own server will have to perform the scraping then send it to the client.

Comment: thanks that's what i'm afraid of, I think i'm gonna stay with python and build a flask website that's gonna be much easier